# Creating a foreach loop using data from a select query?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am trying to update a table based on an Inner Join from 2 other tables. My sql query is:

```
SELECT virtuemart_media_id
     , virtuemart_product_id
  FROM jos_virtuemart_medias m
  JOIN jos_virtuemart_products p
    ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.file_url, '/', -1)
                         , ".", 1)
                      ,"-",1) = p.product_sku 
 WHERE 1
```

What i have so far is:

```
// Start database stuff
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);


//Create query
$query = 'SELECT `virtuemart_media_id`, `virtuemart_product_id` FROM `jos_virtuemart_medias` INNER JOIN `jos_virtuemart_products` ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`jos_virtuemart_medias`.`file_url`, "/", -1), ".", 1),"-",1) = `jos_virtuemart_products`.`product_sku`';

//Set the query

$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadColumn();
```

What i want to do next is loop through and check if the records exist in #__virtuemart_product_medias and if not insert virtuemart_product_id and virtuemart_media_id.

I just cant seem to get my head around loops?

Thank you in advance
Donna

Comment: There should be no need to 'check' anything. And no need to 'select' anything. Just run an INSERT - but this is a terrible way to relate data. Can you not improve on this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, i am trying to automatically assign all images with the product_sku in the title to the products, there is no other way to do this apart from manually, and with over 2000 products i just haven't got the time?